# Javascript module pattern and global variable

Tags: javascript, closures

Seems simple enough, but I cannot get it to work:

```
// Demonstrative only, how can I access canvas from rotate?
_imagePreview = function()
{
    var canvas = '';

    return {

        load: function() {

            fileReader.onload = function(e) {

                image = new Image();

                image.onload = function() {

                    // Empty string (expected)
                    console.log(this.canvas);

                    canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];

                    // Canvas object (expected)
                    console.log(this.canvas);

                    return true;
                }

            }

           image.src = e.target.result;            
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },

    rotate: function() {

        // Undefined (unexpected)
        console.log(canvas);
    }
}
```

I call _imagePreview.load() first, then _imagePreview.rotate(), but I can't seem to get the correct value for canvas.

The rotate method is being called from a click event, after the selects a file and it is drawn into the canvas, so `rotate` will never be executed before `load`. Example:

```
$("#rotate-clockwise").click(function() {

    _imagePreview().rotate('+', 90);
});

$("#rotate-counter-clockwise").click(function() {

    _imagePreview().rotate('-', 90);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `_imagePreview()` multiple times. Each call creates a new set of `load` and `rotate` functions with their own `canvas` variable.

Call `_imagePreview` **once**, store the result call `load` and `rotate` from that object.

Answer (score 0):

That Javascript isn't even valid. Are you getting errors (you will be)? The returned object should look something like this (note the extra enclosing curly braces).

```
return {
    load: function() {
        // ...
    },
    rotate: function() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

If you want to access rotate from load following the sort of approach you are using you might do this:

```
var _rotate = function() {
    // ... do rotation
};

var _load = function() {
    _rotate();
   // ... do some other stuff ...
};

return {
    load: _load,
    rotate: _rotate
};
```

Comment: Didn't want to paste ALL the code in, just the pertinent. Based on your snippet, how can I access variable set in `load` from `rotate`?

Comment: See my edit. You could also make `load` and `rotate` anonymous functions. There are probably many other approaches you could take too.

Answer (score 0):

You simply create the private variables first, then return an object that has functions that use those private variables.

```
_imagePreview = function() {
    var canvas = 'I am a canvas!';

    return {
        load: function() {
            canvas = 'I am a loaded canvas!';
        },
        rotate: function() {
            console.log(canvas);
        }
    };
}

_imagePreview().rotate();
// I am a canvas!

var preview = _imagePreview();
preview.load();
preview.rotate()
// I am a loaded canvas!
```